# Request user certificate from Windows 10 to Windows 2008 R2 certificate authority

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate-authority, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

We have a Windows 2008 R2 server, in the same box we have a stand alone CA (Certificate Authority) and IIS running an ASP application that requires client certificate for access the web app. It is working correctly, but we have starting having problems requesting the user certificates from Windows 10 running IE 11 from certsrv website. We request the certificate using 2048 key size and issue the certificate from the CA console in the server, then from the Windows 10 computer the certificate installs correctly and show that have the private key installed correctly but when we access the web app we got the following errors (1st one for classic ASP and the second from ASPX pages):

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.

We have tried installing the CA certificate from MMC Certificates in the personal and computer stores and problem persists. Also, we tried enabling the web site compatibility in IE and adding to trusted sites.

But we do not have problems with Windows XP computers running IE 6, we request the certificate from certsrv website and the process is easy and works

So far looks like IE 11 is having some problem with the certsrv website. We do not use Firefox or Chrome because the web app was designed to work only with IE.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Limber Jaimes